# C++ Beginner's question on input/output text files.?

Tags: c++, text, input, ascii

If I have an input text with the only thing written of "A" and I want a series of code that will allow me to generate the next ASCII set (B), how would I do so?

```
#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    return 0;
}

#include iostream>
#include fstream>
#include iomanip>
#include string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

ifstream inFile;

ofstream outFile;

    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string character;

    int age;
    double rectangle, length, width, area, parameter, circle, radius, areaCircle, circumference, beginningBalance, interestRate, endBalance;

    inFile.open("inData.txt");
    outFile.open("outData.txt");

    outFile << fixed << showpoint;
    outFile << setprecision(2);

    cout << "Data is processing..." << endl;

    inFile >> length >> width;
    area = length * width;
    parameter = (length * 2) + (width *2);
    outFile << "Rectangle:" << endl;
    outFile << "Length = " << length << " " << "width = " << width << " " << "area = " << area << " " << "parameter = " << parameter << endl;

    inFile >> radius;
    outFile << " " << endl;
    outFile << "Cricle:" <<endl;
    areaCircle = 3.14159 * (radius * radius);
    circumference = 2 * (3.14159 * radius);
    outFile << "Radius = " << radius << " " << "area = " << areaCircle << " " << "circumference = " << circumference;

    outFile << endl;
    outFile << endl;

    inFile >> firstName >> lastName >> age;
    outFile << "Name: " << firstName << " " << lastName << "," << " " << "age: " << age;

    outFile << endl;

    inFile >> beginningBalance >> interestRate;
    outFile << "Beginning balance = " << beginningBalance << "," << " " << "interest rate = " << interestRate << endl;
    endBalance = ((18500 * .0350) / 12.0 ) + 18500;
    outFile << "Balance at the end of the month = $" << endBalance;

    outFile << endl;
    inFile >> character;
    outFile << "The character that comes after" << character << "in the ASCII set is" << character +1;



        inFile.close();
    outFile.close();

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: please don't use "char" as your variable name.  It's a keyword.

Comment: To format code, select it and use the button with the 101010 pattern. If you want to format only a block inside a sentence like `this` use single backquotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of declaring `character` as a `string`, declare it as a `char`. `string` refers to `std::string`, a high-level object for storing multiple characters. `char` is a low-level native type which stores exactly 1 character.

```
char character;
infile >> character;
outfile << "next after " << character << " is " << char(character+1) << endl;
```

input of Z or besides letters notwithstanding.

Comment: Thank you, but now my outdata reads as " The character that comes after A in the ASCII set is 66"

Comment: Sorry, fixed. The problem is that `1` is of type `int`, and `int` is a "bigger" type than `char`, and when you add numbers of different types the result is of the larger type, and hence it printed `B` as an `int`. `outfile << ++ character;` would also print the right thing, but would modify `character`.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!! WOOHOOOO!! I was stumped for soo long and my textbook didn't really go over it. Sincerest Gratitude.

Answer (score 1):

```
char c = 'A';
char next_one = c+1;
```

This gives you the next character ('B' here), assuming ASCII. As this seems to be homework, you need to do the rest of the work by yourself.

Comment: @user 278330: What do you need help with?

Comment: I'm trying to make it so that at the end, the code reads the text file (which contains the letter A), and then will display the next character (so if i put C instead of A in the text file, it will display D)